# Exception when disconnecting GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I just started using the GCDAsyncSocket to connect to my server. The communication between the client and the server works but I get the following exception in the client (Xcode iOS) when the server (vb.net application) disconnects the connection:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: '** -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:]: unable to allocate memory for length (4294967295)'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x16f9012 0x151ee7e 0x16f8deb 0xf2d39e 0xf2cf76 0x2b74f 0x2bd5b 0x175764b 0x16c08fd 0x16c087a 0x16c06ac 0x16c04e7 0x17f855 0x17f926 0x17e2bf 0x182098 0x181ca5 0x1823ff 0x182370 0x7ed53 0x7e59d 0x7e4d0 0x16b9aa8 0x167cf3f 0x167c96f 0x169f734 0x169ef44 0x169ee1b 0x272d7e3 0x272d668 0x462ffc 0x2102 0x2035 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

My GCDAsyncSocket connection blocks look like this:

```
    // Block: Connection established
    [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionOpenedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection established.");
    };

    // Block: Connection fail
    [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionFailedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection) {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed.");
    };

    // Block: Connection closed
    [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionClosedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection) {
        NSLog(@"Connection closed");
    };

    // Block: Message received
    [NetworkController sharedInstance].messageReceivedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection, NSString* message){
        [self processMessage:message];
    };


        [[NetworkController sharedInstance] connect:tHostname];
```

Can anybody give me a hint to that problem?

Thank you in advance!

Greetings
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Before connected your network with chat server please add this line: `[[NetworkController sharedInstance] disconnect];`
Example:

```
[[NetworkController sharedInstance] disconnect];
[[NetworkMessageParser shared] connectWithChatServer];
```